# HP Proliant DL360 not allowing write to drives

Tags: raid

And thanks for stopping by. I bought a server used off Amazon a couple months ago and I can't get it to install an OS no matter what OS/installation method. I can't tell if it's something to do with raid or maybe the BIOS, maybe the drives themselves are faulty. It uses U320 SCSI drives and this is my only server that uses U320 SCSI so without an adapter to sata (which I cannot find) there's no hope of troubleshooting the drives on an already working system. I can boot via USB though, but there's not much I can do because the drives only allow read and format. This is a pre owned system, so maybe the previous owner did something and I'm perfectly willing to reset it in any way, as there's nothing on it (or shouldn't be, at least) at this point idrc what os gets installed, I'm comfortable with both windows and Linux. At this point I'll be happy to get an OS at all.

Answer (score 1):

You should start your installation with HP SmartStart CD. This CD will help you config the RAID and add appropriate drivers to the installation. [Here](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_2e6c41afdb8c4c0d9bffce484c&swEnvOid=4064#) is one possible page from where you can download it. FYI it support Windows, RHEL and SuSE.